# bootstrap operates locally but not fully when live (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a dropdown menu and a carousel with twitter-bootstrap and jquery, and it all works perfectly locally but live it only partially works. The carousel is there but doesn't move and the dropdown menu is there but doesn't 'drop'... help! 
I'm a beginner so its probably obvious but I can't seem to work it out ...
My header is:

```
<head>
    <link href='bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='style1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

Any help would be super appreciated!!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap relies on jQuery, so you need to include jQuery.js *before* bootstrap:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href='bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='style1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

For future reference you should always check the console for errors when dealing with JS issues. I would also suggest you use a CDN for the bootstrap CSS files too.